# executing javascript through url

Tags: javascript

I'm trying to set the value of a textarea on the following page by executing something similar the below javascript:

```
javascript:alert(document.getElementsByClassName('uiTextareaNoResize uiTextareaAutogrow _1rv DOMControl_placeholder')[0].value='blabla');
```

This works if I manually enter the code into the address bar on the target page, but I want to pass this argument through a link.. ie...

```
<a href="/nextpage.php?javascript:alert(document.getElementsByClassName('uiTextareaNoResize uiTextareaAutogrow _1rv DOMControl_placeholder')[0].value='blabla');"
```

Just wondered if anything like this is possible at all?

Comment: Yea.. There is a reason that the browser doesn't let you do this. It is a major security vulnerability.

Comment: it is possible, but then you need a script in the target page, that extracts the string from the url and uses exec() to execute it

Comment: I guess so, unfortunately I don't have access to edit the target page as it's not on my server.

Comment: A URI starts with `scheme:...`. The scheme usually defines how the URL is to be interpreted. E.g. if the URI starts with `http:`, it's a URL. If it starts with `file:` it's a path to a local file. If it is `javascript:` then the browser evaluates the rest as JavaScript. (there's also `ldap:`, `mailto:`, `telnet:`, any many more). If you have a link with `/nextpage.php?javascript:alert(...)`, then you are creating a URL starting with `http:`, e.g. `http://example.com/nextpage.php?javascript:alert(...)`. The `javascript:` is *not* the schema now. It's treated as part of an URL.

Answer (score 0):

You can send the arguments via the url like you would for GET requests. Then have the receiving page parse `location.search`.

For instance, you can send it like this:

```
http://example.com/?arg1=foo&arg2=bar
```

And the receiving page have a script like this:

```
var queryString = location.search; //?arg1=foo&arg2=bar
```

You'll have to parse it manually though, removing the `?`, split by `&` then each by `=`

Comment: Hi, thanks, but this wont work as I don't have access to edit the target page.

Comment: @user3329793 Unfortunately you can't do that. It's a security problem if it were possible. For instance, if it were possible, I can pop-in a script that makes the target page look like a bank login page, fool the user into logging in, and gather their login data.

Answer (score 0):

This is called XSS or Cross-Site-Scripting, and as many comments have already pointed out, it is a security issue. This is why most major browsers do NOT allow it. 
However, I believe that some browsers do allow it, for example Opera - although I can't recall exactly which version. 
If you are looking to make your own "browser", I would recommend using C# .Net WebBrowser, then use the runtime package XULRunner (https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Mozilla/Projects/XULRunner).

Despite all this, I would not recommend doing anything that may be against laws of your current location, or doing anything to displease the site owner.